# VBScript:FileSystemObject.Can i use GetFolder method with absolute url?

Tags: asp-classic, filesystemobject

in ASP-vbscript, I can use the **GetFolder** method of FileSystemObject to get the contents inside a folder if i pass the location of the folder

```
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set folder = fso.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("myfolder"))
```

Can i use the same method with a url instead of foldername

like

```
  Set folder = fso.GetFolder("http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/")
```

When trying this i am getting error

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a004c' 

Path not found
```

I manage the "mysite.com" site.So i can make any folder permissions if needed.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, the `FileSystemObject` is exclusively for managing files.

Within ASP you can use the `Server.MapPath()` method to get the physical path for a relative path or you can use `Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")` to get the base physical path of your application and then use these paths with the `FileSystemObject` but it won't accept URLs

I may be wrong but it should however accept UNC paths so you should be able to connect to network drives to which your computer can connect.